# Java Flux.buffer returns no results until after requested number of elements is buffered

Tags: java, project-reactor

Example below returns buffer only after first 5 elements have been buffered. How to make it return buffers for the first 5 elements also?

```
    @Test
    public void testBuffer() {
        Flux.range(0, 10)
                .buffer(5,1)
                .doOnNext(i -> log.info("tape {}", i))
                .blockLast();
    }
```

Returns:

```
tape [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
tape [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
tape [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
tape [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
tape [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
tape [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
tape [6, 7, 8, 9]
tape [7, 8, 9]
tape [8, 9]
tape [9]
```

desired result:

```
tape [0]
tape [0, 1]
tape [0, 1, 2]
tape [0, 1, 2, 3]
tape [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
tape [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
tape [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
tape [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
tape [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
tape [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
tape [6, 7, 8, 9]
tape [7, 8, 9]
tape [8, 9]
tape [9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any available operator to do such thing.

However, it is possible to combine multiple operators to produce this behaviour :

1. use [Flux#scan](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#scan-A-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to create a sliding/growing buffer. Scan is very useful to accumulate source values in a very customisable way. Note that, however, it is not possible to trigger more buffering/values once the last value has been received. Therefore:
2. We need to create a simple operator that takes the last emitted buffer, and replay it, removing heading values one by one.
3. We need to combine 1. and 2. to obtain the entire sliding. Note that, as I have not found any operator to concatenate a flux produced by the last emitted value of another (in essence, a concatWith which would receive previous flux last value), I will use cache here.

**WARNING** I have absolutely not measured performance impact of such a strategy, it may be bad.

Here is a working prototype :

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ReactorAccumulator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux<Integer[]> growingSlider = Flux.range(0, 10)
                .scan(new SlidingBuffer<>(5, Integer[]::new), SlidingBuffer::accumulate)
                .skip(1)
                .map(SlidingBuffer::getBuffer);

        print("Growing slider", growingSlider);

        var decreasingSlider = growingSlider.last()
                .flatMapMany(buffer -> slideDecrease(buffer, 1));
        print("Decreasing slider", decreasingSlider);

        var slider = thenDecrease(growingSlider);
        print("Growing then decreasing slider", slider);
    }

    private static <V> void print(String title, Flux<V[]> dataStream) {
        var nl = System.lineSeparator();
        var log = dataStream
                .map(Arrays::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(nl, "-- "+ title + nl, nl + "--"))
                .block(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
        System.out.println(log);
    }

    private static <V> Flux<V[]> slideDecrease(V[] buffer, int startIndex) {
        if (buffer.length <= startIndex) return Flux.empty();
        else return Flux.range(startIndex, buffer.length - startIndex)
                .map(from -> Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, from, buffer.length));
    }

    private static <V> Flux<V[]> thenDecrease(Flux<V[]> dataStream) {
        var cacheLast = dataStream.cache(1);
        return cacheLast.concatWith(cacheLast.last()
                .flatMapMany(buffer -> slideDecrease(buffer, 1)));
    }

    static final class SlidingBuffer<V> {

        private final int maxSize;

        private final V[] buffer;

        SlidingBuffer(int maxSize, IntFunction<V[]> creator) {
            this(maxSize, creator.apply(0));
        }

        private SlidingBuffer(int maxSize, V[] buffer) {
            this.maxSize = maxSize;
            this.buffer = buffer;
        }

        SlidingBuffer<V> accumulate(V newValue) {
            final V[] nextBuffer = (buffer.length < maxSize)
                    ? Arrays.copyOf(buffer, buffer.length + 1)
                    : Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 1, maxSize + 1);

            nextBuffer[nextBuffer.length - 1] = newValue;

            return new SlidingBuffer<>(maxSize, nextBuffer);
        }

        V[] getBuffer() {
            // Def copy: might not be needed if you trust consumer code not to modify the array directly
            return Arrays.copyOf(buffer, buffer.length);
        }
    }
}
```

That produces output:

```
-- Growing slider
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
--
-- Decreasing slider
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9]
[9]
--
-- Growing then decreasing slider
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9]
[9]
--
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by [amanin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73499939/10468291), but instead of appending a decreasing buffer at the end of an increasing buffer, I prepend an increasing buffer to the already existing `Flux.buffer`.

This solution also uses `Flux.scan` to create the increasing buffer, but I use [`Flux.publish().refCount(2)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/ConnectableFlux.html#refCount-int-) to create two Flux pipelines, then join them together using `Flux.mergeSequential`. First I let the increasing buffer emit lists while the list is smaller than the buffer size, then I concat this to the lists of `Flux.buffer`:

```java
public static <T> Flux<List<T>> slidingBuffer(Flux<T> flux, int maxSize) {
    Flux<T> sharedFlux = flux.publish().refCount(2);

    Flux<ArrayList<T>> increasingBufferFlux = sharedFlux
            .scan(new ArrayList<T>(), (list, t) -> {
                ArrayList<T> nextItem = new ArrayList<>(list);
                nextItem.add(t);
                return nextItem;
            })
            .skip(1) // first emitted item of Flux.scan is the initial empty ArrayList
            .take(maxSize - 1); // We only need the results smaller than maxSize.

    Flux<List<T>> decreasingBufferFlux = sharedFlux.buffer(maxSize, 1);
    return Flux.mergeSequential(increasingBufferFlux, decreasingBufferFlux);
}
```

Test output:

```java
@Test
public void slidingBufferTest() {
    Flux.range(0, 10)
            .transform(flux -> slidingBuffer(flux, 5))
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .blockLast();
}
```

```bash
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9]
[9]
```

**Edit:** I replaced [`Flux.share()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#share--) with [`Flux.publish().refCount(2)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/ConnectableFlux.html#refCount-int-). `share` will immediately emit items once the first flux (increasingBufferFlux) subscribes, not waiting for the second flux to subscribe, causing the original flux to be evaluated twice. This is fixed by using `refCount(int)`, which will only emit once there are int subscribers.